# How to keep my baby's hand warm at night

Tags: infant, sleep, temperatures

I live in a cold place. The temperature of my house drops to 60°F / 16°C at nights. What is the best way to keep his hands warm?

I've tried mittens, but he puts them in his mouth, which makes them wet, and even colder.

We used to swaddle him, but we're trying to transition him into a sleep sack. The sleep sack is very warm, but the hands are outside the sleep sack.

Comment: Don't check his hands to determine if he's cold. Check his feet. If his feet are warm, he's completely fine.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The best way to keep a baby's hands warm are to make sure his core is warm.  That goes for day or night.

You are on the right track with the sleep sack. I would suggest a wool sleep sack. I've used one for all my kids and they are the best for keeping young babies warm before they are big enough to enjoy a warm blanket safely. But, I've also used cotton and polyester fleece sleep sacks and they can do the job (cotton is better for warmer spring or summer nights though.) Fleece is very warm if you aren't into wool.  However fleece, unlike wool which breathes well and still keeps baby warm when damp, can make a baby sweaty and then he will get a chill because the moisture stays on the baby. I would suggest you give wool a try- it's not scratchy as long as you get a high quality garment and wash it properly (which is very rarely by the way-another advantage to wool.)

As you mentioned, sleep sacks are sleeveless, so you must put something under it. A long sleeve cotton romper is what I usually use, and sometimes on the coldest nights a long sleeve onesie under that. A romper that is a little loose is best so that it traps body heat.

A pair of socks that go up to the knee is a good idea too so that the feet stay warm.

When we lose power and it goes *below* 60 degrees, I would add a hat to the above. One that has a Velcro chin strap is helpful to keep it on once a baby is bigger and moves around a bit at night.

Finally, remember that babies will tell you if they are uncomfortable. They'll cry. So even if your baby's hands do end up a little chilly, if he isn't crying about it (and as long as the rest of him feels warm,) I wouldn't worry about it. He'd tell you if it was a problem.

I hope these suggestions help. Stay warm!

Comment: Thanks. I can't really rely on his crying to let me know if something is wrong, since he frequently cries in his crib for unrelated reasons, such as between his sleep cycles.

Comment: @Jax you answered top notch, I just want to add that the main heat loos is from a babes head a good warm cap will help alot. This experience We had when our babe was born early, was in an incubator the olny thing they put on beside the pamper was a cap. At the time I wondered, the nurse told us. The head is the biggest area of heat loss of the body.

Comment: "the main heat loos is from a babes head" how is that physically possible?https://www.theguardian.com/science/2008/dec/17/medicalresearch-humanbehaviour

Comment: @MontyBom your right by a grown-up. But a baby the head is bigger compared to the body.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you need to worry. Your baby's circulation will still be fine at that temperature, as long as his core is warm. If his chest is warm, and his feet are warm, it really doesn't matter if his hands are a bit cold.

Comment: I understand this is a short answer, but it is correct, nonetheless.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same issue and with the putting in mouth so my little hack is I get thick socks that are not tight and put those over my baby hands once they are asleep to keep them warm.☺